# Android Studio 3.0.1 WebView Reloading page on rotation

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

Hello I've a problem when using my app on the phone, when I rotate the screen inside the app the webview reloads all content getting back to the first page we were opening the app.

I leave you a gif of what happens here and if you know a solution please help me. I also leave my main class and the android manifest.

[Proof Video](https://gyazo.com/f9a4d58e0b16caba5935b3fe8fed0c1b)

[Main.java](https://hastebin.com/icevazotoz.scala)

[AndroidManifest.xml](https://hastebin.com/izanopetih.xml)

Comment: Probably a duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131025/android-preventing-webview-reload-on-rotate.

Comment: Refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1213106

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in your Manifest.xml file

Like below:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.MyTheme">

</activity>
```

Comment: This solution will not reLayout the views

Comment: Not working for me in my AdndroidManifest.xml I added it and not working

Answer (score 0):

Create a fragment to wrap your WebView up. Always return the same WebView in onCreateView, so that a new WebView would not be created on orientation change, thus not reloading.

```
public class MyWebViewFragment extends Fragment {
    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mWebView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (mWebView == null)
            mWebView = new WebView(getActivity());

        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) mWebView.getParent();
        if (parent != null)
            parent.removeView(mWebView);

        return mWebView;
    }
}
```

Add this fragment to your activity.